# Weird string at the end of produced sql - "is null"

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I was trying to select some records from database and it didn't work. So I removed get() method and replaced it with toSql() method to see what is what.

```
  $events = DB::table("events")->where(DB::raw("(Month='$pm' and Day='$pd' and calendar='jalali') or (Month='$mm' and Day='$md' and calendar='gregorian') or (Month='$hm' and Day='$hd' and calendar='hijri')"))->toSql();
    
     dd($events);
```

It gives me this:

```
select * from `events` where (Month='11' and Day='28' and calendar='jalali') or (Month='2' and Day='16' and calendar='gregorian') or (Month='7' and Day='4' and calendar='hijri') is null
```

What is "is null" at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the where clause accept two paramerters at least, you have passed one.

the second parameter is 'null' by default this is why you see 'is null' statement at the end of your query

for raw where, you can use [whereRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#whereraw-orwhereraw)

```
 $events = DB::table("events")->whereRaw("(Month='$pm' and Day='$pd' and calendar='jalali') or (Month='$mm' and Day='$md' and calendar='gregorian') or (Month='$hm' and Day='$hd' and calendar='hijri')")->toSql();
```